# Carrierwave can't find file when testing with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, carrierwave

I'm trying to write an integration test that involves a file uploaded with Carrierwave. I have the following configuration:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  else
    # other configs
  end
end
```

And my uploader has the store path set to:

```
def store_dir                                                                    
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"             
end
```

The outcome of this is that the file gets stored in `public/uploads`. But when I try to access this file via the `doc.url` method on my model, it returns a path like `/uploads/...`, and when running my integration specs I get the following error:

```
unable to open file `/uploads/doc/paper/1/img_1.png'
```

I can confirm that the file does exist in the `/public/uploads` directory. How do I get the Carrierwave to return the correct path to the uploaded image? I could patch it together with `Rails.root.join('public', doc.url)` but that would break in production where we're uploading to S3.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating it some more I realized that the problem here is that we are trying to access the file server side. Client side everything works fine, because it's using relative paths and Rails resolves it as an asset path. Server side it doesn't know where to look. In dev and production we use S3 so the url is the same either way. It feels like a bit of a hack, but where we need to access the image on the server, we did this:

```
path = Rails.env.test? ? doc.img.path : doc.url
file = File.open(path)
```

I wasn't able to find an environment agnostic way to handle this.

Comment: `expect_any_instance_of` and return the `path` value on `url`

Comment: Yeah, that's what we ended up doing for some of them in our tests.